# Flask accept request data as a stream without processing?

Tags: python, flask

I have an endpoint in my Flask application that accepts large data as the content. I would like to ensure that Flask never attempts to process this body, regardless of its content-type, and always ensures I can read it with the `Rquest.stream` interface.

This applies only to a couple of endpoints, not my entire application.

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Werkzeug `Request` object heavily relies on properties and anything that touches request data is *lazily cached*; e.g. only when you actually access the `.form` attribute would any parsing take place, with the result cached.

In other words, don't touch `.files`, `.form`, `.get_data()`, etc. and nothing will be sucked into memory either.

Comment: I started using `stream` and don't appear to have any problems.